# How to dynamically change axios's baseURL from Vue's web page?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm using axios in a Vue project with Spring Boot. I want to test it on both local and cloud (IBM's cloud foundry).

Now I''m using axios like this: in main.js:

```js
var axios = require('axios')
//axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://demoproject2.au-syd.mybluemix.net/api'
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://demoproject1.au-syd.cf.appdomain.cloud/api'
// axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8090/api'
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
```

Every time I upload it to the cloud, I have to change axios' baseURL and rebuild it... 
Is there a better way to do this? Can I change the url from the Vue page?
I have searched, and there are some similar questions like this: [Vue Axios Dynamic URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213240/vue-axios-dynamic-url) But it appears not exactly the question as this...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've created this app from Vue CLI v3, you can define [environment variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) and use those for your various builds.

For example, in your code

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE
```

and in your app directory...

- `.env`

  ```
  VUE_APP_API_BASE=http://localhost:8090/api
  ```
- `.env.production`

  ```
  VUE_APP_API_BASE=https://demoproject1.au-syd.cf.appdomain.cloud/api
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Vue CLI3. But I want to change from the web after the app has been built. For example, in `home.vue` file, I have the `<input value="baseApiUrl">` in `<template>` section. I want to input the baseApiUrl, and use this as the axios baseURL. How to achieve this?